# can i ignore asp files in rails static folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want translate old asp site to rails.

old site has mixup code and static file in one big tree

like

```
   .
   ..
   blabla/
   -img/
   --aaa.jpg
   -js/
   --aaa.js
   blabla.asp 
   blabla2/
   -img/
   --aaa.jpg
   -js/
   --aaa.js
   blabla2.asp
```

it's big site and still replace static files.
and i didn't want sync issue.
so i do

```
ln -s oldfolder/ rails/public
```

static files are no problem but asp codes can look outside. 
i think it's problem.

so my question is, 
how can i pick up some extension(like js,css,jpg) in big spaggette non public folder?
or
how can i ignore some extension(jsp) in public folder?

thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just delete all the .asp files on the production site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache you probably can use this: http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types/ to deny access to the asp files.

Comment: i found it they have wildcard :p
http://routes.groovie.org/manual.html#wildcard-routes
thax anyway :)

Comment: oh ok ... i thought you were using ruby on rails not groovy / grails. :-)
but probably rails has a similar feature